# generate a XML-File and display it in XML-format

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

Looked at a tutorial but couldn't get this working:

default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ContentType="text/xml" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="rssPubba.Default" %>
```

default.aspx.cs

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        // XML declaration
        XmlNode declaration = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration, null, null);
        doc.AppendChild(declaration);

        // Root element: article
        XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("article");
        doc.AppendChild(root);

        // Sub-element: author
        XmlElement author = doc.CreateElement("author");
        author.InnerText = "Faisal Khan";
        root.AppendChild(author);

        // Attribute: isadmin
        XmlAttribute isadmin = doc.CreateAttribute("isadmin");
        isadmin.Value = "true";
        author.Attributes.Append(isadmin);

        // Sub-element: title
        XmlElement title = doc.CreateElement("title");
        title.InnerText = "Sample XML Document";
        root.AppendChild(title);

        // Sub-element: body (CDATA)
        XmlElement body = doc.CreateElement("body");
        XmlNode cdata = doc.CreateCDataSection("This is the body of the article.");
        body.AppendChild(cdata);
        root.AppendChild(body);

        doc.Save(Response.OutputStream);
    }
```

however when I try to display it the browser seem to interpreting it as markup:

output:

```
<article> 
  <author isadmin="true">Faisal Khan</author> 
  <title>Sample XML Document</title> 
  <body><![CDATA[This is the body of the article.]]></body> 
</article>
```

What changes to I have to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it's clearing the output so far and writing the normal page data. Two options:

- Use an ashx instead of aspx to create a handler, so that it knows you're not trying to render the page. That's probably the most sensible approach, if it's *always* meant to be generating an XML document.
- Complete the request when you've written the data, e.g. by calling [`Response.CompleteRequest()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest.aspx)

(I'd also recommend using LINQ to XML as a rather nicer API for constructing XML documents than the old DOM API, but it's up to you :)

Comment: I'm now using LINQ to XML, Response.End(); and a ashx file and it works! Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to use Request." string city = Request.QueryString["city"];" inside ashx?